# username=self.kwargs.get('username') returning Not Found: /

Tags: python, django, django-views

Hi I am trying to set the show the items the is only related to a specific user who is currently logged in.

I have made sure that the user has items under his username. I want to filter the items to be viewed only to the related user. Currently I am getting an error of `Not Found: /` I am not sure why?

Here is the models.py:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

Here is the urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    #path('', home.as_view(), name='home'), <-- Returned not found
    path('user/<str:username>/', home.as_view(), name='home'), <-- Retuned Not found as well
```

I have tried to have a queryset with the filter to the logged in user but returned back the same error.

Here is my views that I have tried

```
class home(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'app_name/base.html'
    context_object_name = 'items'
    # queryset = Item.objects.filter(user=User)


    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        print(user)

    #     return Item.objects.filter(user=user)
```

In the home.html I added:
`{% block head_title %} {{ view.kwargs.username }} | {% endblock %}`

***My question:***

How can I show the list of items that is only related to the logged in user? what am I doing wrong in here?

Comment: i think you can use `self.request.user`  to get the current user ... if that is your question

Comment: @JoranBeasley yes this is correct also but does it does not restrict the other users to view items if different username is used

Comment: It's not clear exactly where the `Not Found: /` error is coming from.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the not found error is raised from inside your view? Maybe you somehow misplaced the URLs and the request can't find the URL. Are you sure that your request reaches the view? You can verify this using a simple print. If not, make sure you've included your urls in the root urls file.

Answer (score -2):

Since self.kwargs is a key value pair, you need to access the val by

```
self.kwargs[f'username']  #f string if it is a variable which it should be.
Not
self.kwargs.get('username')
```

Comment: This answer is not so good.  First of all, `kwargs['username']` and `kwargs.get('username')` are nearly identical -- the only difference is that the `.get()` version will not throw an exception if the key does not exist.  So I have no idea why you would say not to use it.  Second, an F-string is worthless here because there is no `{variable}` in the string.

Comment: Got it. I'm still a newbie at this and thought I could finally help out. Thank you for checking me on this.